# I'm usually short-lived but my fire burns bright - What am I?

Tags: riddle

I'm usually short-lived but my fire burns bright, a site for sore eyes,

A thing for the adventurous or the obsessed, sometimes followers,

There are a lot of us in the army, but they give us the boot,

Those that don't like me might give me a bigger head, give me a break!

**What am I?**

Comment: a **site** for sore eyes? or did you mean to say **sight**?

Comment: @CodeNewbie I did not.

Comment: I was going to ask the same thing.. but didn't want to give away any hints!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it..

> Camp

I'm usually short-lived but my fire burns bright, a site for sore eyes

> Temporary accommodation, campfires burn bright.. a campsite for rest

A thing for the adventurous or the obsessed, sometimes followers,

> Adventure camp, or camping in general, not sure about obsessed (retreats or rehab?)

There are a lot of us in the army, but they give us the boot,

> Bootcamps and there is a lot of camping in the army

Those that don't like me might give me a bigger head, give me a break!

> Not sure about this one.. yet!

**OP explanations**

I'm usually short-lived

> Most camps are temporary

but my fire burns bright,

> Campfire

a site for sore eyes,

> Wordplay! :)

A thing for the adventurous

> Some camp out in the wilderness and the likes,

or the obsessed,

> Others camp out in front of stores etc. ...

sometimes followers,

> As in a "Camp Follower"

There are a lot of us in the army,

> Military encampments

but they give us the boot,

> Boot Camp

Those that don't like me might give me a bigger head,

> Glamping...

give me a break!

> "Break camp"

Comment: Too quick.  You'll have to wait 7 min for your win to be made official...  (thought it was easy but c'mon!) +1 though.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> a flare

I'm usually short-lived but my fire burns bright,

> Flares don't last very long, but they are bright

a site for sore eyes,

> Staring at a flare will make your eyes sore. It will be a site of sore eyes.

A thing for the adventurous or the obsessed,

> Flares can be good in adventurous situations with low light, or for people who like to play with fire

sometimes followers,

> Flares are often used to signal locations that people need to go towards. So they have followers.

There are a lot of us in the army, but they give us the boot,

> There are a lot of them in the army. They throw them away when they use them, hence "give us the boot"

Those that don't like me might give me a bigger head,

> Someone who doesn't like being close to the flare because of brightness might give it more headway when walking around it.

give me a break!

> Parts of the flare often have to be broken in order to use it.

Comment: I realize now that it has already been answered. Well, this makes sense to me.

Comment: Not a bad fit and some good explanations.  +1 at least.  ...once my limit is reset :/